# applying trim for only string variables of the layout in pyspark

Tags: string, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, trim

Is there any easier method to apply trim for only string formatted variables in Pyspark ? Layout has around 500 attributes and I tried below which applies to all. But i want trim to be applied for string only.

```python
 for col in result_df.columns:
        result_df = result_df.withColumn(col,F.ltrim(F.rtrim(result_df[col])))
```

Comment: look at `df.dtypes` and filter out the columns that are not `"string"` type

Answer (score 0):

Using Functools reduce and dataframe dtypes method:

```
from functools import reduce

df = sc.parallelize([
     (1, 'a ', ' a'),
     (1, 'b ', ' b'),
     (1, 'c ', ' d'),
     (2, 'v ', ' f'),
     (3, 'a ', ' e'),
 ]).toDF(["id", "test1", 'test2'])

str_cols = [col  for col, dtype in  df.dtypes if dtype=='string']
trim_df = lambda df, col: df.withColumn(col, F.ltrim(F.rtrim(F.col(col))))

new_df = reduce(trim_df, str_cols, df)
```